# media_youtube plugin doesn't work with ckeditor 4.3.x

Tags: wysiwyg, media

I try to setup D7 + ckeditor 4.3.x in conjunction with wysiwyg + media (v1) modules.

Everything is ok for text edition and image insertion with the media browser button in ckeditor.

The problem is: I try to add the media_youtube plugin and videos do not show in content. Instead I have a placeholder.

Downgraded to ckeditor 3.6 and everything worked perfectly again.

But I'd like to keep the new features in the newer version of ckeditor.

Any idea what the problem could be?

thks

pl.

Comment: Are you seeing the rendered video once you save? I.E., when viewing the node, does the video render? I can't even get that to work, and was wondering if anyone else has.

Answer (score 0):

This just may be a temporary problem with the editor, or a preference setting that may be overlooked. I know the Media module and related modules have had some significant updates and changes, so if that preview feature was unreliable at some point then deactivating it would be the right solution until a better solution comes around.